# Extraer un element dentro de otro element Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, scraping

Estoy intentando extraer datos de un ELEMENT en un WEB con XPATH, la cosa esta que el primer element me aparece así toda el texto junto

`<div class="css-vurnku" style="direction: ltr;">₦50,000.00 - ₦</div>`

y al expandir el ese element me viene mas ordenado y puedo extraer con mas facilidad cada texto

```
"₦"
"50,000.00"
" - "
"₦"
```

El problema esta que al querer tomar digamos `"50,000.00"`El Python se queda cargando un rato y me sale un error de Timeout

Este es el código que estoy utilizando, para tomar `"50,000.00"`

```
Datos2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/main/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/text()[2]')))
    print(Datos2.text)
```

Aquí les dejo una imagen del element cerrado, y otra con el element abierto, para una mejor referencia de lo que quiero tomar

[image: Element Sin Abrir]

[image: Element Abierto]

NOTA: El problema del TimeOut solo ocurre cuando estoy tomando el texto del elemento por dentro `"50,000.00"` ya que el primer elemento que me da toda la información junta no hay problema de TimeOut

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no está pudiendo extraer el `string`. En el caso de que fuera un `string` la solución sería entonces extraer todo el texto y guardarlo en una variable y depués cortar el `string` por las posiciones que te interesan. Es decir hacer esto:

```
Datos2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    numero_raw = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/main/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/text()')))
    numero_real = numero_raw[1:10]
    print(numero_real)
```

**Salida:** `'50,000.00'`

### Actualización

En el caso de que no siempre sean los números iguales, puedes usar expresiones regulares, con el paquete `re` de python, puedes ver más en su [documentación oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). Tu ejemplo quedaría así:

```
Datos2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    numero_raw = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/main/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/text()')))

numero_raw_entero, numero_raw_decimal = numero_raw.split(".")
parte_entera = re.sub("\D","", numero_raw_entero)
parte_decimal = re.sub("\D", "", numero_raw_decimal)
precio = float(parte_entera + "." + parte_decimal)
precio
```

**Salida:** `50000.0`

Que sucede linea a linea:

- `numero_raw.split(".")`: dividimos el string en la parte entera y la parte decimal
- `re.sub("\D","", numero_raw_entero)`: esta expresión regular, quita todo lo que no son números
- `float(parte_entera + "." + parte_decimal)`: unimos la parte entera y la parte decimal y lo convertimos a `float`

Comment: La cosa, es que no siempre tienen la misma cantidad de letra a veces puede ser '50,000.00' después puede ser '500,000.00' y estaría recortando 1 numero, y no puedo saber cuando tiene mas letra o menos letras

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta.